# Do S ranks on special stages help unlock expert stages?

Tags: pokemon-shuffle

I understand that to unlock Expert Stages you must clear a prerequisite amount of stages with a score of S.

Do S ranks achieved on Special Stages count towards unlocking these Expert stages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Expert_Stages):

> Expert Stages in Pokémon Shuffle are unlocked based on the number of
>   Main Stages players win at S-rank (not Pokémon captured). Players
>   cannot access Expert Stages until they complete Stage 12. All Expert
>   Stages are timed-based stages rather than move-based stages.

The table on the site also gives you the following information:

1. HP
2. Time (This is expressed in minutes & seconds)
3. Catch-ability Percentage
4. Required amount of S-Ranks to unlock the stage.

Answer (score 3):

No. Only S ranks on the main stages count towards unlocking Expert Stages.